# Return result form query - showing only on one row

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

it's simple, but I can't do it. I have a query and I want query result to be shown only once. In my code, name of the course is shown so many times as my rows are. I use Codeigniter. My code is:

```
foreach ($timetable as $row) {
    echo $row->course_name;  
}
```

My query is:

```
public function select_timetable() {

        $this->db->select('sequence_num, topic, courses_specific_id, courses_common.course_name,
        courses_specific.course_place, courses_common.courses_common_id, timetable.timetable_id');
        $this->db->from('timetable');  
        $this->db->join('courses_common', 'courses_common.courses_common_id=timetable.courses_common_id');
        $this->db->join('courses_specific', 'courses_specific.courses_common_id=courses_common.courses_common_id');

        $this->db->where('courses_specific_id', $this->input->post('courses_specific_id'));
        $result=$this->db->get();
              return $result->result();
    }
```

And the result of `var_dump($timetable[0])` is:

```
object(stdClass)#27 (7) { 
    ["sequence_num"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["topic"]=> string(10) "HTML tags " 
    ["courses_specific_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["course_name"]=> string(4) "HTML" 
    ["course_place"]=> string(6) "Center" 
    ["courses_common_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["timetable_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
} 

HTMLobject(stdClass)#27 (7) { 
    ["sequence_num"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["topic"]=> string(10) "HTML tags " 
    ["courses_specific_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["course_name"]=> string(4) "HTML"
    ["course_place"]=> string(6) "Center"
    ["courses_common_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["timetable_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
} 

HTMLobject(stdClass)#27 (7) { 
    ["sequence_num"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["topic"]=> string(10) "HTML tags "
    ["courses_specific_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["course_name"]=> string(4) "HTML" ["course_place"]=> string(6) "Center" ["courses_common_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["timetable_id"]=> string(1) "1" } HTML
```

Comment: Would you show us the query please. Plus, what does $timetable show when you var_dump()  or print_r() it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the the results you have to do something like:

```
<?php
foreach ($timetable->result() as $row)
{      
 echo $row->course_name;  
} 
?>
```

If you wanted to only show one row you would need to do something like:

```
if ($timetable->num_rows() > 0)
{
$row = $timetable->row_array(); 
  echo $row['course_name'];
}
```

You can also walk through your different rows like:

```
$row = $timetable->first_row()
$row = $timetable->last_row()
$row = $timetable->next_row()
$row = $timetable->previous_row()
```

Comment: I tried with : $row = $timetable; 
            echo $row['course_name']; and Notice is: Message: Undefined index: course_name

Comment: Did you just copy the whole block of code I put up there? Cause I had 2 errors. And you need to have `$row = $timetable->row_array()` note the `row_array() `. If you dont have that it wont be an array.

Comment: Yes, I have used return $result->result(); because of another query, I made new one with $result->row_array(); and now it's ok, Thank you!

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that your query was already returning result(). Sorry about that. If my answer helped you please accept the answer so people will be able to find it in the future.

Comment: Yes, but I don't have 15 reputation and now I can't..when I have them I'll vote :):)

Comment: Hmm thats strange, I did not know that... I thought you could accept any answer you asked with the check mark but you need at least 15 rep to upvote something. Ha ok, sounds good.

Comment: Yes, I'm newbie here ..for a couple of days.